# psycopg2 TypeError: not all arguments converted to string when passing multiple parameters

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm trying to pass multiple values to my INSERT function using psycopg2. According to the [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries), you must past a list or tuple, which I am doing, but it's still breaking with the following error:

"File "c:\action.py", line 42, in putTicket
    cur.execute(SQL, ins)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

**Code:**

```
data = response.json()                  # get JSON response

record = data[0]                    # header row
col = record.keys()                 # column names
a = []

def putTicket(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()

    for record in data:                     # data rows
        a = []
        y = record.values()                 # values on this row in an array

        for col in y:
            a.append(col)

    ins = tuple(a)

    SQL = "INSERT INTO fd_tickets VALUES (%s)"
    cur.execute(SQL, ins)


print("Using psycopg2...")

myConnection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database, port=port)
putTicket(myConnection)
myConnection.close()
```

Comment: Did you try this: `cur.execute("insert into fd_tickets values %s", [ins])` ? (You should really state the column names in that insert statement.)

Comment: This solved it. And I agree, but does it matter if I'm inserting whole rows every time? The DBs are extremely unlikely to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple values, but only one placeholder. You need as many placeholders as there are values in your tuple.

```
placeholders = ','.join(['%s'] * len(a))
SQL = "INSERT INTO fd_tickets VALUES ({})".format(placeholders)
```